# Animate width of button when text changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to animate the width of the button when the text of it changes. I know I can't use width auto to do this.

My idea was to basically useRef on the button itself, to get the clientWidth of it, and then change a CSS variable to put that width. Then I would use that variable to define the width.

For some reason, the width gets set correctly, but the animation doesn't work. If I edit the CSS on Chrome Developer Tools and change the width from 200px to 400px it works... But when I set it back to the CSS variable and then change the inner text, even though the CSS variable gets updated correctly, the animation doesn't work.

```css
.button {
width: var(--buttonwidth);
transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```js
// When children(text) changes, update css variable
  useEffect(() => {
    const buttonInnerWidth = buttonRef.current.clientWidth;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
      '--buttonWidth',
      `${buttonInnerWidth}px`
    );
    console.log(buttonInnerWidth);
  }, [children]);
```

Does anyone have a better idea of how to do this?

Comment: Could your create a plunker/code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example that changes button width when clicking on that. you can change this listener to anything else you want

example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").css({"width":$("button").text().length*10});
  $("button").click(function(){
    var str = " activated ";
    var strWidth = str.length*10;
    $(this).css({"width":strWidth}).text(str);
  });
});
```

```css
button{
height: 40px;
transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>press</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way too. Almost same as Hooman Namazi's solution, but little bit different approach.
Check this out:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $("button").css({"width":$("button").text().length*10});
    var text = ['first text', 'this is second text', 'and this one is third', 'Hi, I am forth'];
    //used to determine which is the next text to be displayed
    var counter = 0;
    var $button = $('button');
    //repeat the passed function at the specified interval - it is in milliseconds
    setInterval(function () {
        //display the text and increment the counter to point to next text item
        $changeText = $button.text(text[counter++]);
        $button.css({"width":$("button").text().length*10});
        //if it is the last text item in the array point back to the first item
        if (counter >= text.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 2000);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>first text</button>
```

Comment: Yeah I know I could do it like this... But not really good in terms of performance. I ended up using max-width and animating that instead. Then used width auto on button

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to use JS to fix this has performance wise it wouldn't be great to keep checking the width of the text inside the button. Ended up using width: auto and changing the max-width when I change the text inside the button.

Not the perfect solution because you can't give it super long text, but for my use case it works nicely :D

Here you go:

```
.button {
   width: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   max-width: 15rem;
   transition: max-width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);

   &.loading {
     max-width: 30rem;
    }
}
```